# Combustion at 298K

Tags: physical-chemistry, combustion, temperature

**Question:** (source IITJEE 1992)

> An aliphatic thiol undergoes combustion at 298K to give carbon dioxide, water and sulfur dioxide. What are the physical states of the products?(solid/liquid/gas)

I am not able to understand what combustion at 298K means, do they mean the temperature of all reactants and products is 298K ?  In that case, I think the answer would be gas, liquid, gas respectively.

But the answer given is all are gases. Do they mean the room temperature is 298K and the temperature at actual site of the reaction is higher? Is it because it is not possible for combustion to take place at room temperature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. The answer given in my copy of 38 years’ IIT-JEE chemistry has the answer as

$$\ce{CO2 (g), H2O (l), and SO2 (g)}$$

The answer given in your book might be wrong. I don’t think iit released any official answer keys in the subjective days of jee so there may be discrepancies in the answers in different sources.